# sitecore Add users and Media folder after create sub site

Tags: insert, web, sitecore, pipeline

I have a sitecore 7.0 solution with several sites. 
Every time that I add a new site I need to create specific users (author, approver, etc..) and a specific Media Folder to the website.

Question:
Is there any way to make this automatically? I was thinking to play a bit with the pipelines but I'm not sure exactly how to start..

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I have made a custom command for this which:

- asks for a site name (using Context.ClientPage.Start and Context.ClientPage.ClientResponse.Input)
- creates a sites structure based on a template-branch
- creates media library folders

I did not need users but you can add that as well. The only thing left to do manually is adding the configuration files.

There are many blog posts to find about adding custom commands, like:
http://www.sitecore.net/Learn/Blogs/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2013/04/Add-Debug-Command-to-Content-Editor-in-the-Sitecore-ASPNET-CMS.aspx

And also branches:
http://www.sitecore.net/Learn/Blogs/Technical-Blogs/Getting-to-Know-Sitecore/Posts/2012/10/Page-Editor-Secrets-1-Complex-Content-Creation.aspx

Comment: If you used the [Multiple Sites Manager](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Multiple_Sites_Manager.aspx) module then you could add the site "config" programatically too.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions Rvan and jammy! Meanwhile I got into some other bugs and I need to fix before moving to this new feature but I'll definitely give it a go and I'll post something to let you know how it went. Cheers